# Laravel web app deployed on railway but forms does not work on any mobile device

Tags: laravel

So I created a web app using the newest Laravel and I deployed it in railway.app. I ran the migrations and added the .env so it connected with MySQL database. I can register and log in on desktop and laptop view; however, when I am on any mobile device, none of the forms work. I am not able to login or register, it just redirects me back to the same page. I have added error handling to display on the UI, but nothing shows, it just redirects back to the same page. so the data is not saved on mobile view only. I tried different browsers and different network connections. They still do not run. Can someone please help

Comment: *"I am not able to login or register, it just redirects me back to the same page"* - sounds like cookie issue, can you hook your phone to a debugger? i reckon [firefox](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/08/remote-debugging-on-firefox-for-android/) and chrome had adb to enable remote debugging.